# When to use esc_html and when to use sanitize_text_field?

Tags: security, sanitization

It seems that they do almost same type of job. So...

When should I use `esc_html()` instead of `sanitize_text_field()`?

Answer (score 23):

[`esc_html()`](http://queryposts.com/function/esc_html/) is more or less lossless — it just turns HTML markup into encoded visible text, so that it's not rendered as markup by browser.

Semantically it's *escape*, so it's meant to be used to make *output to page* safe.

[`sanitize_text_field()`](http://queryposts.com/function/sanitize_text_field/) however actually removes all HTML markup, as well as extra whitespace. It leaves nothing but plain text.

Semantically it's *sanitize*, so it's meant to be used to make *input being saved* safe.

Comment: isn't it better to use esc_html for both output and saving? I won't display any markup anyway.. so when would i use sanitize_text_field() ?

Comment: @yeahman "better" how? They are doing distinctly different things. Discarding markup usually used for things where markup isn't expected, for example form that takes a name.

Comment: I mean it stores what the user sees and has input... like you said it's lossless..(e.g. he inputs "the tag <head> is where you should include your css files", he expects to see the <head> in his post). 

For a name field, i would control the input via validation; isn't it more suited?

Comment: I'm interested in the differences between `sanitize_text_field()` and `strip_tags`

Comment: strip_tags is used in sanitize_text_field() if I am not wrong

Comment: If you put content into a JSON encoded array, the array values have `"` in them (VERY likely if your content is for example post data) then - while `sanitize_text_field()` WOULD be the right thing to do since you are SAVING data, it will not work. You will need to use `esc_html`, which encodes the `"` and thus, the moment you _decode_ your JSON, will NOT break the returned value.